# Cookie set on the response by Servlet is not available in request of forwarded JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, cookies, forward

I have a simple page where a user would click a button and they would be forwarded to a new page. However accessing the new page without clicking on the button on the previous page can't be done. When the button is clicked it sends a cookie which checks if the button is clicked. This works fine if I use `request.sendRedirect()`. However when using `request.forward()` it doesn't. I have to click the button multiple times before I get sent over to the new page. Below is the code

```
//sends cookie when button is clicked
private void connect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("connect", "connected");
    cookie.setMaxAge(1);
    
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("connectAudio.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

browser checks if cookie exists, if not then this indicates that the button has not been pressed and sends it back to page with button

```
<c:if test="${empty cookie['connect']}">
<c:redirect url="index.jsp">
</c:redirect>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of `redirect` the browser sends two consecutive requests and the second one has the required cookie because it is set by the response to the first request.

In case of `RequestDispatcher.forward(...)` the browser makes only one request which is passed to `connectAudio.jsp`. The required cookie hasn't been set for this first request.

See [this page](https://www.java67.com/2016/03/6-difference-between-forward-and-sendredirect-in-Servlet-JSP.html) and the image on it for more information:

[image]

Comment: Thats a beautiful image you made.

Comment: The image author is [Javin Paul](https://www.blogger.com/profile/15028902221295732276). I wrote above: "See [this page](https://www.java67.com/2016/03/6-difference-between-forward-and-sendredirect-in-Servlet-JSP.html) and the image on it..."